# Trigger click when fie selected and file window browser closed in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do i trigger click when file is selected ?

E.G (what i got so far):

```
  <form name="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="ImageBrowse" size="50" id="ImageBrowse"/> //selected file trigger click on button
   <input type="submit" id="buttonUpload" onclick="return ajaxFileUpload();" style="display:none;"></button>
  </form>
```

The function :

```
$("input").on('keyup', function(){ // what to change here to know if the file selected and the file window browser closed ?
   //do somthing
});
```

What to change in my function to know if the file browser window closed and selected file ?

**EDIT 1 :**

Here what i try so far but stll not working :

```
$("#ImageBrowse,#filename").on('change', function(){
      $("#buttonUpload").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input").on('change', function(){
   //do somthing
});
```

Comment: Not working , any other way? EDIT: i'v update my question with my recent test code but still not working..

Comment: You right , i can't make it work howover i will tag you as Answered, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, reading your example, I understand you have a form with several file inputs and want to submit it as soon as a file is selected. am I right?